# Convergent Sequence Counterexample

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

$\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n = 0$ iff $\lim_{n\to\infty}|s_n| = 0$.

I know this statement is false but I need to find a counterexample and I can't think of one. Any hints??

Comment: The statement is in fact true. That's because $0 = \lvert 0\rvert$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer That isn't the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is actually true.

**Hint** $$|s_n-0|=|s_n|=\bigl||s_n|\bigr|=\bigl||s_n|-0\bigr|$$
Apply the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition of sequence limits.

---

**Added**: In fact, this statement can be generalized. Given any [normed vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space) $\langle V,\lVert\cdot\rVert\rangle$ and any sequence of vectors $\vec s_n\in V,$ we have that $\vec s_n\to\vec 0$ if and only if $\lVert\vec s_n\rVert\to 0,$ since $$\lVert\vec s_n-\vec 0\rVert=\lVert\vec s_n\rVert=\bigl|\lVert\vec s_n\rVert\bigr|=\bigl|\lVert\vec s_n\rVert-0\bigr|.$$

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true and it boils down to unravelling the defintion of limit.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ such that for $n>N$,

$|a_{n}-0|<\epsilon$ iff  $|\text{  }|a_{n}|-0|<\epsilon$.

This is because |x|=||x||. If the sequence is complex, the inner || is the magnitude of the complex number. The outer one is the absolute value.